# Project Organization When Using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Let's say I'm building a software which stores some configuration in a database. My business rules, pages, etc. are in project that I will call *Core*. I have another project, called *Configuration*, which has all the necessary methods to access the database. So:

```
             BusinessComponent                     ConfigurationProvider
       +---------------------------+           +---------------------------+
       |                           |           |                           |
       |                           |  ---->    |                           |
       |                           |           |                           |
       +---------------------------+           +---------------------------+
```

The Configuration object is injected through an interface, `IConfiguration`, into the Business Component.

```
        BusinessComponent              IConfigurationProvider              ConfigurationProvider
  +--------------------------+      +---------------------------+      +---------------------------+
  |                          |      |                           |      |                           |
  |                          | ---> |                           | ---> |                           |
  |                          |      |                           |      |                           |
  +--------------------------+      +---------------------------+      +---------------------------+
```

So, in a sense, both `BusinessComponent` and `ConfigurationProvider` depends on `IConfigurationProvider`.

**The question is**, in which of the two projects, *core* or *Configuration* should `IConfigurationProvider` be?

---

I think that, when using DI, it's best to have the project declare it's dependencies by creating interfaces, and then projects that are interested in providing those implementations, add a reference to this project. It looks definitely like an 'extensibility' approach. (it's a form of Dependency Inversion, isn't it?)

However, this approach is becomes weird when you have more than once project depending on the same configurations -- we would have two similar declarations of `IConfigurationProvider` in this case.

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider having a different project/assembly that will hold all of your interfaces, and your other projects will reference this project. This will also function as an SDK assembly that you'll be able to provide to anyone looking to provide their own implementations, without having to hand out several large assemblies that also contain your own implementations.